# Worklight server 6.1 startup error due to database version n/a

Tags: ant, db2, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

When trying to start worklight server I get the error in systemout:

```
The project /worklight failed to initialize, because the project database schema for data source jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/WRKLGHT is from version N/A, which is not supported by the server from version 6.1.0.00.20131126-0630. Use the Worklight ant tasks to upgrade the project database schema. [project worklight]
```

Which suggests running the ant task to create the db2 database. However this is how I setup the database in the first place, using the commands from the infocenter guide:

```
CREATE DATABASE WRKLGHT COLLATE USING SYSTEM PAGESIZE 32768
CONNECT TO WRKLGHT 
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE TO USER wluser
QUIT
```

then

```
db2 CONNECT TO WRKLGHT USER wluser USING wluserspassword
db2 SET CURRENT SCHEMA = 'WRKSCHM'
db2 -vf <worklight_install_dir>/WorklightServer/databases/create-worklight-db2.sql -t
```

Both these commands completed successfully.

This is a new installation, not an upgrade. I'm using db2 databases (WRKLGT/WLREPORT) with a WebSphere server installation. I have the schema set in the datasource custom properties (current schema value is WRKSCHM),

When I test the data source connection in WebSphere I get success:

```
The test connection operation for data source Worklight Database on server dmgr at node FingertipServerCellManager01 was successful.
```

When I use IBM data studio to view the database, I can see that in the properties, the database version is 8.1 (which seems to be ok - it matches the version I have on another working server)

[image: database version shown in data studio]

Here is the script for creating the database:

```
    --
-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
-- 5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
-- US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
-- disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
--

-- This script creates the tables in the Worklight database,
-- when the database management system is DB2.

-- BEFORE executing this script, you have to have
-- - either an empty database for Worklight,
-- - or an empty schema for Worklight in an existing database.
-- For instructions how to create such a database manually, see the
-- IBM Worklight documentation, section
--   Deploying IBM Worklight projects
--   > Deploying IBM Worklight applications to test and production environments
--     > Deploying an IBM Worklight project
--       > Creating and configuring the databases
--         > Optional creation of databases before you use the Ant tasks
--           > Creating the DB2 databases
-- and section
--   Deploying IBM Worklight projects
--   > Deploying IBM Worklight applications to test and production environments
--     > Deploying an IBM Worklight project
--       > Creating and configuring the databases
--         > Creating and configuring the databases manually
--           > Configuring the DB2 databases manually
--             > Setting up your DB2 databases manually

-- To execute this script:
-- Log in to the database server.
-- First connect to the Worklight database.
-- Let's assume
--   the database name is "WRKLGHT"
--   and the schema name is "WRKSCHM".
-- db2 connect to WRKLGHT
-- db2 set current schema = 'WRKSCHM'
-- Then execute:
-- db2 -tvsf create-worklight-db2.sql


CREATE SEQUENCE ADAPTER_SYNC_DATA_SEQ START WITH 1 CACHE 50;
CREATE SEQUENCE APP_SYNC_DATA_SEQ START WITH 1 CACHE 50;
CREATE SEQUENCE APP_VERSION_ACCESS_DATA_SEQ START WITH 1 CACHE 50;
CREATE SEQUENCE GADGETS_SEQ START WITH 1 CACHE 50;
CREATE SEQUENCE LICENSETERMS_SEQ START WITH 1 CACHE 50;
CREATE SEQUENCE GADGET_APPLICATIONS_SEQ START WITH 1 CACHE 50;
CREATE SEQUENCE NOTIFICATION_DEVICE_SEQ START WITH 1 CACHE 50;
CREATE SEQUENCE NOTIFICATION_USER_SEQ START WITH 1 CACHE 50;
CREATE SEQUENCE USER_PREF_SEQ START WITH 1 CACHE 50;
CREATE TABLE ADAPTER_SYNC_DATA (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, deployable BLOB(1G), deployableHash VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, deployableKey VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID), CONSTRAINT UNQ_deployableKey UNIQUE (deployableKey));
CREATE TABLE APP_SYNC_DATA (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, appDeployableKey VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, deployable BLOB(1G), deployableHash VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, lastPersistentPropertyChange BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID), CONSTRAINT UNQ_appDeployableKey UNIQUE (appDeployableKey));
CREATE TABLE APP_VERSION_ACCESS_DATA (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, ACTION VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, CREATED_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, DOWNLOAD_LINK VARCHAR(254), ENV VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, GADGET_NAME VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, MESSAGE VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, VERSION VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, MULTILANGUAGE_MESSAGES CLOB(1M), PRIMARY KEY (ID), CONSTRAINT UNQ_GADGET_NAMENVVERSION UNIQUE (GADGET_NAME, ENV, VERSION));
CREATE TABLE AUTH_ASSOCIATED_IDENTITY (FROMLOGINMODULE VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, FROMUSERID VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, TOLOGINMODULE VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, LASTACCESS BIGINT, TOIDENTITYSTR CLOB, TOUSERID VARCHAR(254), PRIMARY KEY (FROMLOGINMODULE, FROMUSERID, TOLOGINMODULE));
CREATE TABLE CLUSTER_SYNC (ID VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, HOSTVMID VARCHAR(254), UPDATETIMESTAMP BIGINT, VERSION BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
CREATE TABLE DEVICES (DEVICE_ID VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, FRIENDLY_NAME VARCHAR(254), USER_ID VARCHAR(254), DEVICE_OS VARCHAR(254), DEVICE_MODEL VARCHAR(254), DEVICE_ENV VARCHAR(254), CERT_SERIAL_NUM VARCHAR(254), LAST_ACCESSED_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, STATUS SMALLINT, PRIMARY KEY (DEVICE_ID));
CREATE TABLE LICENSE_TERMS (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, ACT_DEVICES BIGINT NOT NULL, APP_COUNT BIGINT NOT NULL, INACT_DEVICES BIGINT NOT NULL, REPORT_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, SERVER_COUNT BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
CREATE TABLE GADGETS (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, DISP_IN_GALLERY SMALLINT, LAST_UPDATE_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID), CONSTRAINT UNQ_ UNIQUE (NAME));
CREATE TABLE GADGET_APPLICATIONS (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, ENFORCE_AUTHENTICITY SMALLINT, ENVIRONMENT_ID VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, SERVER_VERSION VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, VERSION VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, VERSION_LOCKED SMALLINT, GADGET_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
CREATE TABLE GADGET_DEVICE_ASSOC (DEVICE_ID VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, GADGET_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, CERT_SERIAL_NUM VARCHAR(254), STATUS SMALLINT, PRIMARY KEY (DEVICE_ID, GADGET_ID));
CREATE TABLE GADGET_USER (GADGET_APP_ID VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, USER_ID VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, FIRST_ACCESS_TIME DATE NOT NULL, GADGET_ID VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (GADGET_APP_ID, USER_ID));
CREATE TABLE GADGET_USER_PREF (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, GADGET_APP_ID VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, USER_ID VARCHAR(254), VALUE CLOB, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
CREATE TABLE NOTIFICATION_APPLICATION (APPLICATIONID VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, MEDIATORTYPE SMALLINT NOT NULL, PLATFORMSTR VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, dataStr CLOB, ENABLED SMALLINT, PRIMARY KEY (APPLICATIONID, MEDIATORTYPE, PLATFORMSTR));
CREATE TABLE NOTIFICATION_DEVICE (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, ALIAS VARCHAR(254), APPLICATIONID VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, DEVICE VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, OPTIONS VARCHAR(254), PLATFORM VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, TOKEN VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, USERAGENT VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, USERSUBSCRIPTIONID BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
CREATE TABLE NOTIFICATION_MEDIATOR (MEDIATORSTR VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, stateStr CLOB, PRIMARY KEY (MEDIATORSTR));
CREATE TABLE NOTIFICATION_USER (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, EVENTSOURCE VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, state CLOB, USERID VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID), CONSTRAINT UNQ_USERIDEVENTSOURCE UNIQUE (USERID, EVENTSOURCE));
CREATE TABLE OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE (ID SMALLINT NOT NULL, SEQUENCE_VALUE BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
CREATE TABLE PROPERTIES (PROPERTY VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, VALUE VARCHAR(254), PRIMARY KEY (PROPERTY));
CREATE TABLE SSO_LOGIN_CONTEXTS (DEVICE_ID VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, DEVICE_LOGIN_MODULE VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, SSO_LOGIN_MODULE VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, LOGIN_CONTEXT CLOB(1M), EXPIRES TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (DEVICE_ID, DEVICE_LOGIN_MODULE, SSO_LOGIN_MODULE));
CREATE TABLE USAGE_DATA (TIME_AT_BEGINING_OF_DAY BIGINT NOT NULL, USER_ID VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, EXACT_LOGIN_TIME BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (TIME_AT_BEGINING_OF_DAY, USER_ID));
CREATE TABLE WORKLIGHT_VERSION (WORKLIGHT_VERSION VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
CREATE INDEX I_GDGTTNS_GADGET ON GADGET_APPLICATIONS (GADGET_ID);
CREATE INDEX I_NTFCDVC_PARENT ON NOTIFICATION_DEVICE (USERSUBSCRIPTIONID);
CREATE INDEX I_NTFCDVC_DEVICE ON NOTIFICATION_DEVICE (DEVICE);

INSERT INTO WORKLIGHT_VERSION(WORKLIGHT_VERSION) VALUES ('6.1.0');
```

---

I've recreated the db2 databases, and this issue seems to have gone away, however I now get a different error message:

```
[7/25/14 15:36:11:451 BST] 00000061 LocalContaine I     org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'WorklightPU'
```

Comment: Check what version of `create-worklight-db2.sql` file your are using to create `WRKLGHT` DB in the DB2.

Comment: You say "the database version is 8.1". But the minimum supported DB2 version for Worklight is DB2 9.7. Also check that your DB2 JDBC driver is matching your DB2 version; the list of DB2 JDBC driver versions is at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866

Comment: @KawineshSK I have added the create script to my question. This is the default script installed with Worklight (<worklight_install_dir>/WorklightServer/databases/create-worklight-db2.sql)

Comment: @slowhand The DB2 version is 10.1, the database version is 8.1 (I have the same config working on a different server). The JDBC driver is using db2jcc4.jar, from the directory created in the DB2 installation (<installpath>\SQLLIB\java\)

Comment: @kevyn OK DB2 10.1 with the JDBC driver from the same DB2 installation is known to work fine.

Comment: @slowhand when using IBM data studio (updated question with screenshot)

Comment: The error message "... is from version N/A" can occur if the application server is accessing a different schema than the one you intended. Can you show the declaration of the data source in your application server's configuration (without the password, of course)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57908/discussion-between-kevyn-and-slowhand).

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to re-create the database tables, and the original issue has gone away.

Regarding the mentioned error:

> [7/25/14 15:36:11:451 BST] 00000061 LocalContaine I
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
>   createNativeEntityManagerFactory Building JPA container
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'WorklightPU'

This is actually a warning, and not an error. And it can be safely ignored per the following support document: 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21605316